# Any chance for Indy 10 to output Unicode with Delphi 6?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, indy10, delphi-6

I gave a try for Indy 10 on Delphi 6.

The problem is - with old Indy I was able to output Unicode through UTF-8 as AnsiString by setting proper encoding in `ResponseInfo.ContentType`. Now I lost the Unicode output. Here is an example how did I output an unicode string with old Indy:

```
var
  MyUnicodeBodyString: WideString;

function MyUTF8Encode(const s: WideString): UTF8String;
var
  Len: Integer;
begin
  Len := WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, PWideChar(s), Length(s), nil, 0, nil, nil);
  SetLength(Result, Len);
  if Len > 0 then
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, PWideChar(s), Length(s), PAnsiChar(Result), Len, nil, nil);
end;

begin
  // ...
  AResponseInfo.ContentText := MyUTF8Encode(MyUnicodeBodyString);
end;
```

When I do the same with Indy 10, the output is like

> РўРѕРІР°СЂ

(the UTF-8 string where each byte is encoded as Unicode then).

When I change the output to just

```
AResponseInfo.ContentText := MyUnicodeBodyString;
```

I see the normal output of ASCII and of symbols for "language for non-Unicode programs" (in Windows control panel). Other languages are garbled.

Indy 10 is programmed with "string" and probably assumes that "string" is WideString, but in Delphi 6 string is an alias for AnsiString.

Can I influence the output of Indy 10 HTTP Server without replacing every string in Indy 10 source code with WideString ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Indy 10 is programmed with "string" and probably assumes that "string" is WideString

That is incorrect.  Indy's existence predates Delphi's switch to Unicode in Delphi 2009, so Indy has a lot of backwards compatibility for handling `AnsiString` in Delphi 2007 and earlier.  In those versions, Indy does not use or assume `WideString` anywhere in its public API (well, except for in the `IIdTextEncoding` interface), everything is based on `AnsiString` instead.

> in Delphi 6 string is an alias for AnsiString.

Yes, exactly.  Which is why the *preferred* way to send non-ASCII content in an older ANSI version of Delphi is to use ANSI-encoded strings, eg:

```
var
  MyAnsiBodyString: AnsiString;
...
AResponseInfo.CharSet := 'utf-8';
AResponseInfo.ContentText := MyAnsiBodyString;
...
```

If the `AnsiString` is encoded in the default OS ANSI codepage (as it typically should be), then Indy will simply convert the `AnsiString` to Unicode using that codepage by default, and then encode that Unicode result as UTF-8 for transmission.

> Can I influence the output of Indy 10 HTTP Server without replacing every string in Indy 10 source code with WideString ?

Yes.  In pre-Unicode versions of Delphi, most of Indy's components/classes have additional properties/parameters to specify an ANSI byte encoding, allowing Indy to properly convert an `AnsiString` to Unicode before `charset`-converting the Unicode to bytes for transmission (and vice versa on reception).

So, if you want to send an `AnsiString` that is already pre-encoded as UTF-8, one approach is to manually set the `AResponseInfo.ContentLength` property, as well as the `IOHandler.DefAnsiEncoding` property, eg:

```
var
  MyUtf8Str: UTF8String;
...
MyUtf8Str := MyUTF8Encode(MyUnicodeBodyString);
AResponseInfo.CharSet := 'utf-8';
AResponseInfo.ContentText := myUtf8Str;
AResponseInfo.ContentLength := Length(myUtf8Str);
AContext.Connection.IOHandler.DefAnsiEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
...
```

If you don't set the `ContentLength` manually, `TIdHTTPResponseInfo.WriteHeader()` will calculate that value for you, by converting the `ContentText` to `WideString` using the RTL's default ANSI->Unicode conversion, and then encoding that `WideString` to UTF-8 to get the byte count. However, the initial ANSI->Unicode conversion will not know your `AnsiString` is encoded in UTF-8 and thus will not process it correctly.

If you don't set the `DefAnsiEncoding` manually, `TIdIOHandler.Write()` will use the default `DefAnsiEncoding` setting of `IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault` to convert the `ContentText` to Unicode using the OS's default ANSI codepage, which is likely not UTF-8 and so will not convert the text to Unicode properly before then encoding the Unicode result to UTF-8 bytes.

Another approach is to use `AResponseInfo.ContentStream` instead of `AResponseInfo.ContentText`.  That way, you can simply store your UTF-8 bytes in a `TMemoryStream` or `TStringStream` and then `TIdHTTPResponseInfo.WriteContent()` can send those bytes as-is, eg:

```
AResponseInfo.CharSet := 'utf-8';
AResponseInfo.ContentStream := TStringStream.Create(MyUTF8Encode(MyUnicodeBodyString));
```

Or:

```
var
  MyUtf8Str: UTF8String;
...
MyUtf8Str := MyUTF8Encode(MyUnicodeBodyString);
AResponseInfo.CharSet := 'utf-8';
AResponseInfo.ContentStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
AResponseInfo.ContentStream.WriteBuffer(PAnsiChar(MyUtf8Str)^, Length(MyUtf8Str));
AResponseInfo.ContentStream.Position := 0;
```

Or:

```
AResponseInfo.CharSet := 'utf-8';
AResponseInfo.ContentStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
WriteStringToStream(AResponseInfo.ContentStream, MyUTF8Encode(MyUnicodeBodyString), IndyTextEncoding_UTF8, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
AResponseInfo.ContentStream.Position := 0;
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked like a charm! Now I can have a mixture of different languages again.